# How can I determine when the page exits is because of form submiting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, confirm

Here is my code:

```
// confirm alert before close page
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
    var el = document.getElementById("qandatextarea");
    if( el && el.value && !DontAskBeforeExit){
        var message = 'are you sure you want to exit this page?';
        if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
            evt = window.event;
        }
        if (evt) {
            evt.returnValue = message;
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

Please focus on this line:

```
if( el && el.value && !DontAskBeforeExit){
```

Well there is three conditions:

- `el`: checks whether is that textarea exists in the DOM ?
- `el.value`: checks has that textarea any value? (in other word, isn't that textarea empty?)
- `!DontAskBeforeExit`: it is a variable which is either `0` or `1`. When the content of that textarea is stored into localStorage, it is `1`, otherwise it is `0`.

Ok, now I need to one more condition. I need to check "is the page submitting or exiting"? I mean, I don't need to show that pop-up alert if the user is sending a post *(submitting)*. How can I do that?

Comment: Been asked before, onsubmit, set flag saying it is a form submission...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766658/window-onbeforeunload-only-show-warning-when-not-submitting-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// set a flag so teh function isn't called twice on the form submit
var formsubmitted = false;

document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function(evt){
    formsubmitted = true;
    exitPage(evt, "formsubmit");
};

window.onbeforeunload = function(evt){
    // we don't want this to fire twice when the form is submitted
    if(!formsubmitted) exitPage(evt, "naturalunload");
}

// added an extra parameter , name, and condition to your original function
function exitPage(evt, exitType) {
    var el = document.getElementById("qandatextarea");
    if( el && el.value && !DontAskBeforeExit && exitType=="formsubmit"){
        var message = 'are you sure you want to exit this page?';
        if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
            evt = window.event;
        }
        if (evt) {
            evt.returnValue = message;
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```